# Windows 7 Colors (PNG darker in browsers)

Tags: windows-7, windows, firefox, colors, png

A few days ago I installed **f.lux**, and since then I've noticed that my PNG images look darker in Firefox. I've never encountered such a problem before. It doesn't work with it (**f.lux**) disabled either. I did a little research and I came to the conclusion that it's all about PNG embedded color profile. So I was testing it out, making screenshots of my desktop, video player, etc. and it looks always darker in browser. I was making those screenshots with the <kbd>PrntScr</kbd> button on my keyboard and pasting it into Paint and then viewing the result in both Windows Preview and in browser.

So I checked my Windows colors management and it's all set to default. I was testing all I knew I could in both Windows colors and in NVIDIA control panel and it worked somehow and it looked same in both browser and Windows Preview. After I rebooted my PC, it's all gone and it's looking darker again. I have no clue which one worked and which didn't.

So I've made screenshot the same way I did before in safe mode and it looks OK.

Tested in normal mode with all non-Microsoft services off and all autorun programs off and it looks darker.

Tested with same OS version on virtual machine in normal mode and it looks OK.

I know that I can just switch `gfx.color_management.mode` in Firefox to 0 and it will look OK, but that's not the solution.

While doing those tests I checked those PNG files info and when it looks darker in browser it has additional tag named “sRGB Mode” set to “Perceptual”. In a normal PNG file there is no such tag at all. So I'm guessing that, while saving screenshot to PNG in Paint, Windows adds this tag. So, finally, the question is:

How can I fix it without reinstalling Windows?

Screenshots: GOOD:

[image: GOOD screenshot]

and BAD:

[image: BAD screenshot]